# Почему в vk api для python не работает метод "messages.send()"?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже как второй день не могу разобраться в чем проблема, в библиотеке vk не работает метод `messages.send()`, все что нужно я предоставил: id приложения, свой логин и пароль. Но почему этот метод не работает, я никак понять не могу. Пишет, что отказано в доступе, но причина отказа там даже не написана :\
вот фото, ошибку подчеркнул зеленой чертой
[image]

спасибо

Comment: @I TT попробуйте сделать `vkapi = vk.API(session) vkapi.messages.send(...)`

Comment: в смысле просто изменить переменную на vkapi? тогда я сделал как Вы сказали, все равно не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте скрипт, например `test_vk.py`. В него вставьте этот код (с изменением значений переменных):

```
import vk

app_id, login, password = 'app_id', 'login@vk.com', 'password'
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id, login, password, scope='messages')
vk_api = vk.API(session, v='5.62')

vk_api.messages.send(user_id="304601652", message='hello world!')
```

И запустите его командой `python test_vk.py`

Comment: наконееец-то))))) оказывается, нужно было еще аргумент вставить "scope='messages'", даже админы группы "Вконтакте api" не могли помочь.. спасибо!))

Comment: @I TT на здоровье!